# Does the DC-DC converter have any effect on the microphone?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, microphone

I have had audible sound problems with some dc-dc converters. Especially the noises coming from the inductor.
I need to use the [this](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/LX7167_Rev1.1.pdf)  converter in a circuit that includes a microphone as well.
[This](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/218/SPM1423HM4H-B-876897.pdf) is the microphone that i plan to use. This type microphones mostly are sensitive up to 20kHz.
Switching frequency of the buck-converter is 3MHz. Distance between the MIC and DC-DC is about 40-50mm on the PCB.
Would switching frequency cause background noise sound captured by the MIC?

Comment: I would not drive a audio devices directly from a switching converter without filtering and/or an additional linear regulator unless I was ok with having some of the power supply noise end up in the audio.

Comment: Please show schematic and layout of said converter. If done properly, you should not pick up anything.

Comment: What do you mean with "properly", did you understand the question?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the switching frequency that will get into your analog signal. It's the HF high harmonics and the LF modulation due to low power mode.

When output current is low, most buck chips use some strategy to save power, like cycle skipping or burst mode. Your chip is a hysteretic DC-DC, so it will reduce frequency. If output power is low enough, for example in standby mode, frequency (or frequency of bursts) can get low enough that it becomes audible, and then your inductor and ceramic cap whistle. This is due to magnetostriction in the inductor (it gets mechanically squeezed by current), and MLCCs are pretty good piezoelectric loudspeakers too. So you should check if that happens. If frequency gets low enough, the microphone can pick it up through the power supply too.

When output current is high enough, a fixed frequency buck it will run at its nominal frequency. This is a hysteretic converter though, so frequency will strongly depend on load current. This could mix with another close frequency in your design and cause a beat frequency in the audible range, which your microphone may also pick up. This can also couple through the power supply, and the beat frequency can appear as ripple.

The mic looks well shielded, so I would only worry about its power supply since its PSRR is rather low. So you could power it from a LDO to give it a clean VCC. However, its supply current is also very low, so you could just use a RC filter on the power supply, or both.

Comment: It was interesting to learn dependency of switching frequency to output current. I wish there could be a way to simulate it.